# Find all functions that haven't been granted access permissions, in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I'm using CakePHP's ACL functionality. I want to find all functions in a project that have not been granted access permissions for a specific group?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this problem, here is a tool that does it.

https://github.com/notoriousturtle/cake-acl-auditor